# Merge two tables with different column names KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I have two tables IdentityInfo and AuditLogs so I need to merge with these two columns AccountDisplayName(IdentityInfo) and Identity(AuditLogs).
I found this on microsoft information but no information related with this issue.

```
IdentityInfo
|join kind=inner AuditLogs on AccountDisplayName,[CommonField]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by *merge* you mean *join*, and that the value in the column `AccountDisplayName` have an equality match with those in the column `Identity`, then the following should work.

Though, you probably want to apply filters/aggregations on at least one of the `join` legs, depending on the size of the data sets being joined.

```
IdentityInfo
| join kind=inner AuditLogs on $left.AccountDisplayName == $right.Identity
```

Documentation of the `join` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator